# Sql query with: inner join, between (datetime) and where id=value

Tags: c#, sql

my query:

```
SELECT  Hospedagem.Id_hospede, checkin, checkout, nome
FROM [Hospedagem]
where Id_casa=5 inner join Hospedes on Hospedes.Id_hospede= Hospedagem.Id_hospede
where checkin BETWEEN '" + before + "'  and '" + after + "'
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
> 'inner'.

query i did before works nicelly:

```
SELECT Id_casa, Hospedagem.Id_hospede, checkin, checkout, nome
FROM [Hospedagem] inner join Hospedes on Hospedes.Id_hospede= Hospedagem.Id_hospede
where checkin BETWEEN '" + before + "'  and '" + after + "'
```

How to get functional the first mentioned query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `JOIN` is an operator in the `FROM` clause.  `WHERE` is a clause that follows the `FROM` clause.  I'm voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Only one WHERE clause and should go after all the FROM/JOIN clause

Comment: And after fixing that typo, please read carefully [about Sql Injection](https://www.bing.com/search?q=what+is+sql+injection&cvid=b45f31904cbd4d4b9fd1c26a2efe5ea5&aqs=edge.2.69i57j0l6.8409j0j1&pglt=899&FORM=ANNTA1&PC=U531) and how your query is vulnerable to this very common hack

Comment: Try removing WHERE and see if you get any results.  Also check the ID to see in both cases if they id is same type.  Either both strings or both numbers.

Comment: Please remove the `c#` & `.net` tag from this question. It's purely database & sql

Comment: Thank you all for the help. The given answer worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  Hospedagem.Id_hospede
        ,checkin
        ,checkout
        ,nome
FROM    Hospedagem
        INNER JOIN Hospedes ON Hospedes.Id_hospede = Hospedagem.Id_hospede
WHERE   checkin BETWEEN '" + before + "' AND '" + after + "'
        AND Id_casa = 5;
```